# An odd assignment about adding dashes to strings. PHP

Tags: php, string, recursion, replace

I have a need for a function that will do the following thing:

If I have a string like this `"2 1 3 6 5 4 8 7"` I have to insert dashes between pairs of numbers following some rules.

The rules are simple.

Put a dash between two numbers if the first one of the pair is smaller then the one that follows it. Do all possible combinations of this and if a pair already has a dash then the space next to it can't have a dash.

Basically my results for above string would be

```
2 1-3 6 5 4 8 7
2 1-3 6 5 4-8 7
2 1 3-6 5 4 8 7
2 1 3-6 5 4-8 7
2 1 3 6 5 4-8 7
```

I did create a function that does this but I am thinking it is pretty sluggish and I don't want to taint your ideas with it. If possible I would like to know how you guys are thinking about this and even some pseudo code or code would be great.

EDIT 1:
here is the code I have so far

```
$string = "2 1 3 6 5 4 8 7";

function dasher($string){
   global $dasherarray;
   $lockcodes = explode(' ', $string);

   for($i = 0; $i < count($lockcodes) - 1; $i++){
      if(strlen($string) > 2){
         $left = $lockcodes[$i];
         $right = $lockcodes[$i+1];
         $x = $left . ' ' . $right;
         $y = $left . '-' . $right;
         if (strlen($left) == 1 && strlen($right) == 1 && (int)$left < (int)$right) {
            $dashercombination = str_replace($x, $y, $string); 
            $dasherarray[] = $dashercombination;
            dasher($dashercombination);
         }
      }
   }
   return array_unique($dasherarray);
}

foreach(dasher($string) as $combination) {
   echo $combination. '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Please show us what you have already done and explain what you think is wrong with it. Don't be afraid to "taint our ideas with it", there are people around here with enough experience to ensure such a thing won't happen. However - we do like to see askers's effort, it gives us motivation that they did try it by their own (rather then asking strangers as the first attempt to solve the problem), and the answer is more likely to be better for you - since it will guide you to the solution.

Comment: What I think is wrong with it is that I think I would like to avoid recursion and possibly not invoke str_replace. I tried toying with simply replacing str_replace with $string[($*2)-1] = '-' but I am not getting the intended result.

Comment: I edited the entry amit.thank you for looking at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this will be helpful in terms of offering different methods to parse the string.

```
$str="2 1 3 6 5 4 8 7";
$sar=explode(' ',$str);
for($i=1;$i<count($sar);$i++)
  if($sar[$i-1]<$sar[$i])
    print substr_replace($str,'-',2*($i-1)+1,1) . "\n";
```

Note that the code expects only single digits numbers in the string.

Note that the code expects that the string is formatted as per your example. It would be good to add some sanity checks (collapse multiple spaces, strip/trim blanks at the beginning/end).

We can improve upon this by finding all the spaces in the string and using them to index substrings for comparison, still assuming that only a single spaces separates adjacent numbers.

```
<?php
$str="21 11 31 61 51 41 81 71";
$letter=' ';
#This finds the locations of all the spaces in the strings
$spaces = array_keys(array_intersect(str_split($str),array($letter)));

#This function takes a start-space and an end-space and finds the number between them.
#It also takes into account the special cases that we are considering the first or 
#last space in the string
function ssubstr($str,$spaces,$start,$end){
    if($start<0)
        return substr($str,0,$spaces[$end]);
    if($end==count($spaces))
        return substr($str,$spaces[$start],strlen($str)-$spaces[$start]);
    return substr($str,$spaces[$start],$spaces[$end]-$spaces[$start]);
}

#This loops through all the spaces in the string, extracting the numbers on either side for comparison
for($i=0;$i<count($spaces);$i++){
    $firstnum=ssubstr($str,$spaces,$i-1,$i);
    $secondnum=ssubstr($str,$spaces,$i,$i+1) . "\n";
    if(intval($firstnum)<intval($secondnum))
        print substr_replace($str,'-',$spaces[$i],1) . "\n";
}

?>
```

Note the explicit conversion to integers in order to avoid lexicographic comparison.

Comment: A string can not be longer than 8 digits and digits can not be higher than 8. Digits are separated by a space in initial string but in my sample secondary generated strings can already contain dashes. The first code sample you created does not provide correct solution. if you look at the sample results i posted there are possible double pairs in the same string.

Comment: Any time someone says, "The rules are simple", you can almost bet that that's not really the case. You're pulling more rules out on me @user1743071! I'll suggest these as alternative ways of processing the string, but it's still up to you to find a way to ultimately solve the problem.

Comment: Well they are simple on paper when they write the assignment :) otherwise I share your sentiment on 'simple rules'. My function above works more or less ok,, I was really hoping to eliminate str_replace and do that part somehow better. Or even to avoid recursion (which I am still working on)

Comment: Thanks for looking at this Richard, I will see if I can apply your ideas to improve mine.